# Selecting rows in 2-D numpy array based on subset of column values

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have the following numpy array:

```
a = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]])
```

I want to select only the rows, where column with index 1 have value 1 and column with index 2 have value 0.

i tried the following:

```
evidence = {1:1,2:0}
mask = a[:,list(evidence.keys())] == list(evidence.values())
```

But after that i am stuck.
how can I do it in numpy 2-D array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
out = a[(a[:, 1] == 1) & (a[:, 2] == 0)]
```

Given a dictionary of column, value pairs, you could use:

```
evidence = {1:1,2:0}
out = a[ np.logical_and.reduce([a[:, c] == v for c, v in evidence.items()]) ]
```

which generalizes the above solution to a sequence of `&`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! this works, how can it be done in general(for n columns)? For example if I have a dictionary with n key_value pairs?

Comment: See the edited solution. The `evidence` being a dictionary feels a bit awkward to me though. If that is something you can change, I would